# Replicating android gallery view

Tags: android, architecture, gallery, android-contentresolver, fileobserver

I am working on a project to replicate android gallery and want to add some information against few media files, that need to create own database for media files information.

The issue here is if I save all current existing media path in db then how can I sync with any kind of file changes made(added/removed media file).
**What is best way of doing this ?** without looking for all directory structure every time and searching all media files.

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: I tried File Observer to getUpdate about file changes but it gives only one level file changes in dir.
Looked for Contentresolver  which can map Files "MediaStore.Files" which is available from API level 11 onward.